# What should a proper GET request and response look like in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, get

I am working on a small project using Node.js.

The objective is to send an HTTP Request to an array of websites and display what they return to me.

[First someone helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22717912/2236166) to figure out that I needed a specific Node.js module (XMLHttpRequest). So I "required" it after installing it with NPM. Then I instantiate it.

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );

//I don't think I need this
xmlHttp.send(null);

//Log some stuff to the console, namely the "response"
console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
console.log(xmlHttp.statusText);
console.log("Finished!");
```

Now I believe what this will do is send a GET message to "theUrl", and then save the response in the xmlHttp Object's responseText member.

So now I should have a response. I should be able to print that as text (console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);). What should be in this response?

I expect to get something like "200 OK" but that is nowhere in the response I get. Am I going about this in the right way?

I plan on using the Async Node.js module to send a request like this to an array of URLs, trim up their response (name of the website name, the response status code, and each of the response headers).

Comment: This should help http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

Comment: Rather than trying to simply duplicate browser code, if you are using node, it would be easier to just use the [`request` module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/request). I think you would find it simpler to use. There is a reason it is the #3 most-depended on package on NPM. Also, because of how much it is used, you will have a bigger pool of potential help if you have questions about it.

Comment: Can you explain this? I am requiring xmlHttpRequest...is there much difference?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below;

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
        // responseText => response body as string
        // status => 200 is OK, 404 page not found
    }
};

xhr.open("GET", "yor_url");
xhr.send();
```

**responseText**: response body as string

**status**: 200 is OK, 404 page not found